# Acess support please

Tags: ms-access, vba

[Access Docment scanned with Macfee and Microsoft on a server platform One drive so completly safe.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FB12C936CCABCB44!17640&authkey=!ACPaVbEwIJbdlu8&ithint=file%2Caccdb)

I want a user login page which has different levels so that different users will have access to different objects or functionality.

Please have a look at the coding below I have also attached a link to onedrive for the access 2013 document.

code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Security As Integer
    Me.txtLogin = Environ(“userName”)

    Me.txtUser = DLookup(“userName”, “tblUser”, “Username = ‘” & User & “‘”)Then
    If IsNull(DLookup(“userSecurity”, “tblUser”, “UserLogin = ‘” & Me.txtLogin & “‘”)) Then
        MsgBox (“No User security set up for this user. Please contact the Admin”, vbOKOnly, “Login Info”

        Me.NavigationButton13.Enabled = False
    Else
        Security = DLookup(“userSecurity”, “tblUser”, “UserLogin = ‘” & Me.txtLogin & “‘”)
        If Security = 1 Then
            Me.NavigationButton15.Enabled = True

        Else
            Me.NavigationButton15.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us what happens with the code you have now.  Is there an error message?  If so, what is the message and which line triggers it?  If no error, please describe the differences between what that code does and what you need it to do.

Comment: `Me.txtUser = DLookup(“userName”, “tblUser”, “Username = ‘” & User & “‘”)Then` seems to be something extra or missing on this line ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a main login page for the entire app, which is the startup form. Keep in mind that a user can hold down the Shift key when opening your app to bypass any startup code, but you can disable that. You can also hide the database container. Users can always use another DB to link your tables, or import objects, so you will also want to lock the entire database with a password.

The form startup code can check your custom security table and then you can use Cancel = True to short-circuit the opening event. It seems like you are trying to accomplish that by disabling navigation buttons, but you may want to disallow the opening of the form.

As HansUp and Tim have suggested, tt would be helpful if you can describe your situation a bit more so that we can respond more concisely. If you have a situation where you need true security that is hard to breech, you may want to consider moving your tables into SQL Server (or SQL Express) and linking them to your Access container. Ultimately, there's nothing you can do in Access that I could not get around.